# What is the serialization pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

I've seen it referenced in a couple places but I've been unable to find a description of the pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To me, this means a specific form of the [Memento pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memento_pattern). The Mementos, in this case, are Serialized objects. The Caretaker is the file system.

Comment: Seems reasonable.  FYI another name for the Memento pattern is apparently "Snapshot".

Answer (score 2):

I feel very uncomfortable with the Memento perspective.

For me, THE principal purpose of serialisation is making a graph transportable in time and space.  This is, because graphs are fine for direct processing, while series are fine to modulate [electromagnetic or acoustic] waves, magnetisations on a harddisk or black-and-white on a sheet of paper. 
{have a look at eg. http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html for a better understanding.

The elements of such series are very elementary things, which are beyond the scope of responsibility of the graph representation {"not part of the address space"} -- and NOT objects.
Further, I would not easily accept, that eg. the vacuum, which "transports" electromagnetic waves, shall take over the responsibility of the caretaker.
And, [de]serialisation better is not the responsibility of a single object|originator: think of a parser {"deserialiser"}, where the grammar is in the best position to be responsible for the process, and not the single nodes of the AST.

Moreover, serialisation and deserialisation are often context-dependent.
Eg. think of a serialisation of RMI to IIOP on the sender side of the communication channel and a deserialisation from IIOP to Corba on the receiver side.  The two graph representations before sending and after receiving may resemble some structure {probably, what we would call the semantics}, but[, if serialisation and deserialisation are not inverse to each other,] are considerably different things and NOT the same "originator".

What I would rather accept, is to consider a series as a particular [accidentally serial] representation of a graph -- in our modern MIME-world other possible representations being eg. 2D- or 3D- images, ... .  One could consider these representations as the "signs", the "surface", the "syntactical" as opposed to the "semantical" on the graph side {I'm saying this, since FOPL statements are canonically transformable into graphs and vice versa}.
From this perspective, it may make sense to associate the model-view-controller pattern and look at [de]serialisation as the process, the controller performs, the graph then taking over the model role and the representation the view role.
But this is also not a perfect match, since it stands my "two different graphs"-criticism above, just as little.

I know, that this could only have been inspiring, not in the least exhaustive.  So, I'm curious about any cortex-ual reflections...